# Continuous surjection of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ onto the interior of the $n$-simplex with continuous right inverse

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $n$ be a positive integer.  Clearly $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and the interior of the $n$-simplex $
\delta_n := \{x \in [0,1]^n:\,\Sigma_k x_n =1, (\forall i)\,x_i>0\}
$ are homeomorphic.  What I'm looking for is much weaker, however.  Namely, does anyone know of an explicit continuous surjection:
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow \delta_n,
$$
which has a *continuous right-inverse*?

**Update:**
Consider the maps
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_1:\mathbb{R}^{n-1} & \rightarrow (0,1)^{n-1}\\
x & \mapsto \frac1{2}\cdot \left(1+ \frac{x_k}{1+|x_k|}\right)_{k=1}^{n-1}\\
f_2:(0,1)^{n-1} & \rightarrow \delta_n\\
x & \to \frac{\|x\|_{\infty}}{\|x\|_1} x I_{x\neq 0};
\end{aligned}
$$
then, isn't $f_2\circ f_1$ a homomorphism; so in particular setting $f=f_2\circ f_1$ satisfies the conditions we are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Delta\subset \mathbb R^{n-1}$ be an isometric copy of $\delta_n$ with barycenter in the origin. Let $j:\mathbb R^{n-1}\to[0,+\infty)$ be the  associated Minkowski functional, defined by $x\in j(x) \partial\Delta $ for all $x\in \mathbb R^{n-1}$. Then $x\mapsto \frac {j(x)}{j(x)+1}x$ is a homeo $\mathbb R^{n-1}\to \Delta$.

Comment: (of course this is made really explicit once the affine isometry $\delta_n\to \Delta$ is given)

Comment: I believe the affine map $A:R^n\ni (x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ restricts to an affine isometry from the hyperplane $M:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\, \sum_k x_k =1 \}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ (whose inverse is $(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})\mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k)$.  However, what is the gauge $j$ on $A(\Delta)$?

Comment: I Updated my post; I think I have a closed-form similar to the one you wrote down..